# How to check for one Perl regex pattern while excluding another

Tags: regex, perl

As an example, if I need to filter the following text and search for the word `example`, but omit results in which the line begin with a hash `#`

```
# filler text example
example
example 2
# test example 3
```

I've tried a few different combinations, but cant seem to get this right.

**Update**

I've tried `/^[^#].*example/g` and `/^(?!#).*example.*/g` but didn't seem to get any results

Comment: `'^(?!#).*example.*'`

Comment: tried this before, but still didn't work

Comment: Could you edit your question instead to demonstrate what you tried?

Comment: Please don't link to off-site resources unless you have no choice. The external page may not be available for future readers of your question, and it's frustrating to have the information spread across multiple pages

Comment: It is a common habit to add a `/g` modifier *"for luck"* without any thought as to what it might be doing. Please read [**Global matching**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl), and get into the habit of *only* using a language construct when you have a reasonably complete understanding of what it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is strangely common to attempt to bundle far too much functionality into a single regex, while people don't seem to do the same thing with any other operator.

There is nothing wrong with writing

```
if ( /example/ and not /^#/ ) {
  print;
}
```

and it is far clearer than any single equivalent regular expression

You could change this to multiple statements if you wish; something like

```
while (<>) {
  next if /^#/;
  print if /example/;
}
```

Or you could allow comments to start in the middle of a line by creating a temporary variable that contains the text with all characters from the hash `#` onwards removed, and process that instead

```
while (<>) {
  my ($trimmed) = /^([^#]*)/;
  print if $trimmed =~ /example/;
}
```

**Note** that if you are hoping to process Perl code using this, then there are cases which will have to receive special treatment where a hash doesn't denote the start of a comment, such as the `$#array` construct, or an alternative pattern delimiter like `m#example#`

Comment: +1  Agreed concerning people's tendencies to want to be clever with regexes to the detriment of clarity and robustness of their code.

Comment: Thanks, completely changed the way I think about this :D

Comment: @SimpsonDanny: You're welcome. Please evangelise these ideas!

Answer (score 0):

`^((?!#).*example.*)$` will work better with your regex101 tester.  Also use the flags `gm` instead of just `g`.   The tester is processing the sample text as a single string, but devnull's answer works if you're processing the text line by line.